# How can I export a mesh with multiple UV maps?

Tags: mesh, uv, export, bump

So I have two UV maps. One is a UV map for my bump map and other texture, while the other is just for the base texture. I want to export my mesh (it's a single mesh) while keeping both UV maps and being able to import the bump and texture maps without having to do anything else. FBX and OBJ are preferably what I want to export as.

Comment: yes with fbx but not with obj. Blender will automatically add All the uv maps to fbx as shown here - 
https://blenderartists.org/t/exporting-fbx-obj-file-with-multiple-uv-maps-only-active-uv-exports-correctly/630610

Comment: alternatively you can bake one uv map's texture to a new bump texture on the first uv map if you need obj